# ANTLR3 Dynamic quotes in lexer

Tags: antlr, antlr3

I need to match something like the Perl regexp matcher

```
m/my regex!*/
```

where the quotes can be any character from a range. So the above is the same as

```
m%my regex!*%
```

A naive guess of a lexer rule would be

```
REGEX: 'm' quote=. (~(quote))* quote;
```

but that does not work, because the latter `quote` is not referring to the `quote=` but to some rule.

I can do it with a lot of own code, like

```
REGEX: 'm' quote=. { ... implement the loop and final match myself ... } ;
```

but somehow I think there should be a canonical way to do such things.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> ... but somehow I think there should be a canonical way to do such things.

There is not. You'll have to do this with custom code.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at PL/SQL parser ([here](https://github.com/porcelli/plsql-parser/blob/master/parsers/PLSQLLexer.g)). Oracle also supports those Perl style quoted strings.

Like:

```
q':select * from employees where last_name = 'smith':'
```

Use the custom code as an example. (It contains C and Java implementation).
Maybe in your case it can be even simplified.

Ivan

Comment: That is astoundingly close to what I came up with for the simple case. It got a bit nasty later when I wanted to convert \-escapes in the lexer. Even if you did not actually answer my question I'll upvote you anyway to help other people looking for a solution.