# How to parse dynamic delimiter using antlr?

Tags: antlr, antlr4

I am trying to parse the following command from Cisco IOS config:

`banner exec <d> <message> <d>`

where `<d>` is the delimiting character of user's choice—a pound sign (#), for example. The `<message>` cannot use the delimiting character in it.

It seems that I will need to use semantic predicates for it. But couldn't figure out a way to do it.

Yang

Answer (score 1):

As long as you know the delimiter in advance, you can use something like this. You can modify `isDelimiter` to support any single-character delimiter.

```
@lexer::members {
    private boolean isDelimiter(int c) { return c == '#'; }
}

Message : Delimiter NotDelimiter* Delimiter;
fragment Delimiter : {isDelimiter(_input.LA(1))}? . ;
fragment NotDelimiter : {!isDelimiter(_input.LA(1))}? . ;
```

Comment: That is the tricky part. The delimiter is not known ahead of time. It is only known in the actual file.

Comment: Any help on this one is really appreciated. I think this is a challenging problem, and many people can benefits from an answer on it.

Comment: Found a similar post here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14286870/antlr3-dynamic-quotes-in-lexer